# How do I save "color configs" command in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

Recently , i was learning about windows cmd commands.

I was blocked with a command `color 2e` , which will change the foreground and background color of the interface.

i can change it and the foreground and background color has been applied successfully , but after i closed and reopen again. the color has return to the default.

so how should i do to fix it ,i do not want to modify other files,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works this way from UI:

1. Open cmd.
2. Type `color 2e`.
3. Click on the icon at the top left of the window.
4. Click on `Properties`.
5. Click `OK`.

Now you can close the window and it saved color settings (if it won't work please try the dame but select `Defaults` in step 4 - it seems there is a difference for some versions of Windows).

Default colour settings are stored in registry, for example you may have a look into 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DefaultColor` and the same for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DefaultColor` trying exporting\importing it.

They contain two-digit hexadecimal value where first digit stands for background color and the second one for text color. Color codes are like this:

```
0 - black
1 - blue
2 - green
3 - aqua
4 - red
5 - purple
6 - yellow
7 - white
8 - grey
9 - light blue
A - light green
B - light aqua
C - light red
D - light purple
E - light yellow
F - bright white
```

So that you can configure the color theme you like, export the registry to *.reg file and reuse later

Comment: thank you very much, select and config `Defaults` in step 4  did work , thanks again